# Acer notebook freeze / sleep on boot Debian 9.5

Tags: debian, boot, wifi, freeze, realtek

When booting Debian 9.5 my notebook, Acer Aspire E5 - 573G sleeps for several minutes before the login screen shows up. It stops after the following lines:

```
[   10.686470] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[   10.686471] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[   10.686483] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[   10.697700] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin (-2)
[   10.769505] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
[   10.769516] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 target 0x05020000 chip_id 0x003820ff sub 11ad:0806
[   10.769519] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 0 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   10.770353] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[   10.889620] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin
[   10.890373] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 93da0176
```

I can see a delay on the `dmesg`output:

```
[   29.927760] r8169 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw
[   29.978604] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   29.978711] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   30.056531] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   31.986034] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   33.921973] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   34.250085] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  309.280237] random: crng init done
```

There is another delay here:

```
[  413.201803] kauditd_printk_skb: 11 callbacks suppressed
[  413.201804] audit: type=1400 audit(1544884039.293:23): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi///usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" pid=1737 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1430.253104] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 6c:38:a1:3e:3d:cd by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1430.268820] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
```

but I am not sure that this has something do to with the issue.

So I strongly suspect the problems is coming either from the Atheros Wifi or the Realtek, though  `firmware-realtek` and  `firmware-atheros` packages are installed and cable and wifi connections do work without any problems that I see.

Content of `etc/network/interfaces` file is:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```